# Laravel Problem last login, Time is stamped in every row

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'am Use Laravel Authentication Event for last login ,But there was a problem when the time stamped to every row
my code in column 'LAST_LOGIN'
I want it to be recorded only in the logged-in user.But it looks like The login time will be saved to every user.
As the picture that I attached.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcBHA.jpg)

app\Listeners\UpdateLastSignInAt

```
    <?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class UpdateLastSignInAt
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }
    public function handle(Login $event)
    {
        $event->user->LAST_LOGIN = Carbon::now();
        $event->user->save();
    }
}
```

\app\User.php  --model--

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
    protected $table = 'SYSM_USERS';

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $primaryKey = null;

    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'ID', 'USER_NAME', 'PASSWORD', 'FIRST_NAME', 'LAST_NAME', 'DEPART_ID','E_MAIL','NOTE','STATUS','LAST_LOGIN','CREATED_BY','CREATED_DATE','UPDATED_BY','UPDATED_DATE'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'PASSWORD', 'remember_token',
        ];

        protected $dates = ['LAST_LOGIN','CREATED_DATE','UPDATED_DATE'];

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->attributes['PASSWORD'];
    }

}
```

\app\Providers\EventServiceProvider

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Auth\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $listen = [
        Registered::class => [
            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        ],
        'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
            'App\Listeners\UpdateLastSignInAt',
        ],

        'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered' => [
            'App\Listeners\LogRegisteredUser',
        ],

    ];
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        //
    }
}
```

my login controller

```
public function login(){ 
if(Auth::attempt(['USER_NAME' => request('USER_NAME'), 'password' => request('PASSWORD')])){ 
    $user = Auth::user(); 
    return response()->json(['success' => 'success'], $this-> successStatus);  
} 
else{ 
    return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401); 
}
```

}

Comment: See if getting the `user` in a `user` variable and updating the `last login at` works. `$user = $event->user` `$user->LAST_LOGIN..` `$user->save`

Comment: if you are using ```Carbon::now()``` in the **Listener** it will take the Current time literally the time on which the **job is Processing**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i can do it,I use WHERE into function handle ,to be specific

app\Listeners\UpdateLastSignInAt

```
        <?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class UpdateLastSignInAt
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }
    public function handle(Login $event)
    {
        $date =  Carbon::now();
        $user = $event->user->ID;
        User::where('ID', $user)
              ->update(['LAST_LOGIN' => $date]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you override the login method in authController?????
like this

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    if (method_exists($this, 'hasTooManyLoginAttempts') &&
        $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        $user = auth()->guard('web')->user();
        //$user = auth()->guard('api')->user();
        $user->last_login = now()->toDateTimeString();
        $user->save();
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

Comment: this is different attempt. he is trying to Queue the Work. But you are suggesting a synchronous process.

Comment: It is good to distribute responsibilities to different classes. Doing different stuff in a single method will be violating good design patterns.

Comment: Sorry,My problem is when logging in. The time should be added to the logged in user. But it is added every user

Comment: how is your login?

Comment: @Mehdi Log in with `Auth::attempt`

Comment: I dont understand        your problem !!!!!!!!!!!!!
 auth()->guard('web')->user(); or auth()->guard('api')->user() returned only current logged in user not all user and $user->save(); save only auth user